# Как привязать ToolStripDropDown к форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте.
Нашел пример всплывающего контрола:

```
private readonly ToolStripDropDown _toolStripDropDown = new ToolStripDropDown
{
    CanOverflow = true,
    AutoClose = false,
    DropShadowEnabled = true,
};

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var trk = new TrackBar();
    var host = new ToolStripControlHost(trk)
    {
        Margin = Padding.Empty,
        Padding = Padding.Empty,
        AutoSize = false,
        Size = trk.Size,
    };

    _toolStripDropDown.Size = trk.Size;
    _toolStripDropDown.Items.Add(host);
}

/// <summary>
/// По клику на кнопку опказывается ToolStripDropDown под кнопкой
/// </summary>
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pt = this.PointToScreen(button1.Location);
    pt.Offset(0, button1.Height);
    _toolStripDropDown.Show(pt);
}
```

Как можно привязать всплывающий контрол (`ToolStripDropDown`) к положению контрола на основной форме (`button1`)? При отключенном автозакрытии (`AutoClose = false`).
Сейчас проблема такая: если производить какие-то манипуляции с формой (например перетаскивая или масштабируя ее), мой всплывающий контрол будет висеть на том же самом месте. Есть ли уже готовые решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Как вариант можно подписаться на событие формы `Move`/`LocationChanged` и на каждом срабатывании пересчитывать и устанавливать новое местоположение для `ToolStripDropDown`.

Comment: Этот вариант очень сложен (затратен), Т.к. если мой контрол (в данном случае кнопка), будет расположен во множестве контейнеров (группбоксы. ,панели, в других контролах, которые также могут быть в контейнерах), то придется подписываться на изменения Move/LocationChanged, всех контролов в этой иерархии, т.к. они тоже могут быть перемещены :(
Хочется найти вариант попроще